# BeautifulSoup does not scrape full content from a Trulia.com search results page

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape some data from trulia.com search results page. Each trulia page contains exactly 40 listings and I need to scrape {price, #beds #bath #address} for each listing using beautifulsoup.

The problem is that the script below does not return full list of elements the page contains, but only 7 first listings out of 40. Hence the list containers "Bed", "Bath" "Address" also contain only 7 first entries, while 40 is expected.
Interestingly I successfully used this code about 2 month ago and it worked as intended, scraping all 40 entries from each page.
What is the problem and how can I overcome it?

```
import requests
from urllib.parse import urlencode
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd 
import urllib.parse
import json
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

url = "https://www.trulia.com/for_sale/Hartford,CT/1p_beds/1p_baths/1p_sqft/SINGLE-FAMILY_HOME_type/"

API_KEY = 'MY_SCRAPERAPI_KEY'
params = {'api_key': API_KEY, 'url': url}

response = requests.get('http://api.scraperapi.com/', params=urlencode(params))
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

results = soup.find(id="resultsColumn")
elements = results.find_all("div", class_="Text__TextBase-sc-27a633b1-0-div Text__TextContainerBase-sc-27a633b1-1 ewcDjf keSfom")

prices=[]
for el in elements:
    p=el.text
    prices.append(p)
    print(el.text)
    
Bed=soup.select('[data-testid="property-beds"] ')
Bath=soup.select('[data-testid="property-baths"] ')
Addr=soup.select('[data-testid="property-address"] ')
```

I learned that lazy-loading can be the reason why the script above stopped working, so I tried to modify my code using Selenium, but did not succeed, it still returns only 7 first entries.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import requests
from urllib.parse import urlencode


url = "https://www.trulia.com/for_sale/Hartford,CT/1p_beds/1p_baths/1p_sqft/SINGLE-FAMILY_HOME_type/"
API_KEY = 'MY_API_KEY'

def get_scraperapi_url(url):
    """
        Converts url into API request for ScraperAPI.
    """
    payload = {'api_key': API_KEY, 'url': url}
    proxy_url = 'http://api.scraperapi.com/?' + urlencode(payload)
    return proxy_url


chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
driver.get(get_scraperapi_url(url))
time.sleep(5)  # wait for the page to load

# Scroll down to load all the listings
last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
while True:
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    time.sleep(2)
    new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    if new_height == last_height:
        break
    last_height = new_height

# Get the HTML content and parse with BeautifulSoup
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

# Extract the listings details
results = soup.find(id="resultsColumn")
elements = results.find_all("div", class_="Text__TextBase-sc-27a633b1-0-div Text__TextContainerBase-sc-27a633b1-1 ewcDjf keSfom")

prices=[]
for el in elements:
    p=el.text
    prices.append(p)
    print(el.text)
    
Bed=soup.select('[data-testid="property-beds"] ')
Bath=soup.select('[data-testid="property-baths"] ')
Addr=soup.select('[data-testid="property-address"] ')  

# Close the browser
driver.quit()
```

Comment: If "api.scraperapi.com" isn't able to get dynamically loaded content, then calling that API through selenium, won't work either.

Comment: @gre_gor, it does work using selenium. you can see the solution below.

Comment: @AjeetVerma OP is calling an API through selenium not the page directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can get the data about all 40 lists(homes).

```
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome, ChromeOptions
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
import selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions as EC

options = ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")

driver = Chrome(options=options)

response = driver.get("https://www.trulia.com/for_sale/Hartford,CT/1p_beds/1p_baths/1p_sqft/SINGLE-FAMILY_HOME_type/")
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'ul[data-testid="search-result-list-container"]')))

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
data = soup.find('script', {"id": "__NEXT_DATA__"}).text
json_data = json.loads(data)
homes = json_data['props']['searchData']['homes']

homes_data = []
for home in homes:
    homes_data.append({
        'address': home['location']['fullLocation'],
        'coordinates': home['location']['coordinates'],
        'price': home['price']['formattedPrice'],
        'link': 'https://www.trulia.com'+home['url'],
        'bedrooms': home['bedrooms']['formattedValue'],
        'bathrooms': home['bathrooms']['formattedValue'],
    })

print(homes_data)
print(len(homes_data))
```

output:

```
[{'address': '17 Whiting Rd, East Hartford, CT 06118', 'coordinates': {'latitude': 41.75663, 'longitude': -72.63926, '__typename': 'HOME_Coordinates'}, 'price': '$244,900', 'link': 'https://www.trulia.com/p/ct/east-hartford/17-whiting-rd-east-hartford-ct-06118--2004864749', 'bedrooms': '3bd', 'bathrooms': '2ba'}, {'address': '35 Shadow Ln, West Hartford, CT 06110', 'coordinates': {'latitude': 41.73251, 'longitude': -72.751526, '__typename': 'HOME_Coordinates'}, 'price': '$499,000', 'link': 'https://www.trulia.com/p/ct/west-hartford/35-shadow-ln-west-hartford-ct-06110--1063205863', 'bedrooms': '3bd', 'bathrooms': '2ba'}, {'address': '194 Branford St, Hartford, CT 06112', 'coordinates': {'latitude': 41.79863, 'longitude': -72.69995, '__typename': 'HOME_Coordinates'}, 'price': '$120,000', 'link': 'https://www.trulia.com/p/ct/hartford/194-branford-st-hartford-ct-06112--2004848778', 'bedrooms': '3bd', 'bathrooms': '2ba'}, {'address': '836 Prospect Ave, Hartford, CT 06105', 'coordinates': {'latitude': 41.773373, 'longitude': -72.714935, '__typename': 'HOME_Coordinates'}, 'price': '$739,000', 'link': 'https://www.trulia.com/p/ct/hartford/836-prospect-ave-hartford-ct-06105--2004797196', 'bedrooms': '6bd', 'bathrooms': '4ba'}, {'address': '6 Haynes Rd, West Hartford, CT 06117', 'coordinates': {'latitude': 41.78482, 'longitude': -72.7334, '__typename': 'HOME_Coordinates'}, 'price': '$379,900', 'link': 'https://www.trulia.com/p/ct/west-hartford/6-haynes-rd-west-hartford-ct-06117--2004861292', 'bedrooms': '3bd', 'bathrooms': '2ba'}, {'address': '575 Mountain Rd, West Hartford, CT 06117', 'coordinates': {'latitude': 41.783073, 'longitude': -72.76635, '__typename': 'HOME_Coordinates'}, 'price': '$545,000', 'link': 'https://www.trulia.com/p/ct/west-hartford/575-mountain-rd-west-hartford-ct-06117--2004860826', 'bedrooms': '3bd', 'bathrooms': '4ba'}, {'address': '105 Hartford Ave, Newington, CT 06111', 'coordinates': {'latitude': 41.714645, 'longitude': -72.7221, '__typename': 'HOME_Coordinates'}, 'price': '$286,000', 'link': 'https://www.trulia.com/p/ct/newington/105-hartford-ave-newington-ct-06111--2004835115', 'bedrooms': '3bd', 'bathrooms': '2ba'}, {'address': '160 Harding Ave, Newington, CT 06111', 'coordinates': {'latitude': 41.709923, 'longitude': -72.73317, '__typename': 'HOME_Coordinates'}, 'price': '$294,900', 'link': 'https://www.trulia.com/p/ct/newington/160-harding-ave-newington-ct-06111--2004837571', 'bedrooms': '2bd', 'bathrooms': '2ba'}, {'address': '19 Cornell Rd, West Hartford, CT 06107', 'coordinates': {'latitude': 41.748463, 'longitude': -72.75974, '__typename': 'HOME_Coordinates'}, 'price': '$579,900', 'link': 'https://www.trulia.com/p/ct/west-hartford/19-cornell-rd-west-hartford-ct-06107--2004807092', 'bedrooms': '3bd', 'bathrooms': '3ba'}, {'address': '6 Old Oak Rd, West Hartford, CT 06117', 'coordinates': {'latitude': 41.787216, 'longitude': -72.767296, '__typename': 'HOME_Coordinates'}, 'price': '$399,900', 'link': 'https://www.trulia.com/p/ct/west-hartford/6-old-oak-rd-west-hartford-ct-06117--2004861305', 'bedrooms': '3bd', 'bathrooms': '3ba'}, {'address': '345 Auburn Rd, West Hartford, CT 06119', 'coordinates': {'latitude': 41.776436, 'longitude': -72.73012, '__typename': 'HOME_Coordinates'}, 'price': '$520,000', 'link': 'https://www.trulia.com/p/ct/west-hartford/345-auburn-rd-west-hartford-ct-06119--2004874172', 'bedrooms': '4bd', 'bathrooms': '3ba'}, {'address': '41 Steep Hollow Ln, West Hartford, CT 06107', 'coordinates': {'latitude': 41.731915, 'longitude': -72.76247, '__typename': 'HOME_Coordinates'}, 'price': '$649,900', 'link': 'https://www.trulia.com/p/ct/west-hartford/41-steep-hollow-ln-west-hartford-ct-06107--2004809291', 'bedrooms': '4bd', 'bathrooms': '3ba'}, {'address': '12 Woodmont Rd, West Hartford, CT 06117', 'coordinates': {'latitude': 41.803677, 'longitude': -72.75183, '__typename': 'HOME_Coordinates'}, 'price': '$449,000', 'link': 'https://www.trulia.com/p/ct/west-hartford/12-woodmont-rd-west-hartford-ct-06117--2004857480', 'bedrooms': '3bd', 'bathrooms': '4ba'}, {'address': '86 Hills St, East Hartford, CT 06118', 'coordinates': {'latitude': 41.74081, 'longitude': -72.60012, '__typename': 'HOME_Coordinates'}, 'price': '$189,000', 'link': 'https://www.trulia.com/p/ct/east-hartford/86-hills-st-east-hartford-ct-06118--2004870911', 'bedrooms': '2bd', 'bathrooms': '1ba'}, {'address': '92 Lafayette Ave, East Hartford, CT 06118', 'coordinates': {'latitude': 41.73601, 'longitude': -72.619934, '__typename': 'HOME_Coordinates'}, 'price': '$140,000', 'link': 'https://www.trulia.com/p/ct/east-hartford/92-lafayette-ave-east-hartford-ct-06118--2004871209', 'bedrooms': '2bd', 'bathrooms': '1ba'}, {'address': '26 Briarwood Rd, West Hartford, CT 06107', 'coordinates': {'latitude': 41.746475, 'longitude': -72.76434, '__typename': 'HOME_Coordinates'}, 'price': '$329,000', 'link': 'https://www.trulia.com/p/ct/west-hartford/26-briarwood-rd-west-hartford-ct-06107--2004807915', 'bedrooms': '3bd', 'bathrooms': '2ba'}, {'address': '29 Ranger Ln, West Hartford, CT 06117', 'coordinates': {'latitude': 41.777344, 'longitude': -72.75849, '__typename': 'HOME_Coordinates'}, 'price': '$462,500', 'link': 'https://www.trulia.com/p/ct/west-hartford/29-ranger-ln-west-hartford-ct-06117--2004859361', 'bedrooms': '3bd', 'bathrooms': '3ba'}, {'address': '161 Marlborough St, Newington, CT 06111', 'coordinates': {'latitude': 41.669212, 'longitude': -72.746124, '__typename': 'HOME_Coordinates'}, 'price': '$299,900', 'link': 'https://www.trulia.com/p/ct/newington/161-marlborough-st-newington-ct-06111--2004837607', 'bedrooms': '3bd', 'bathrooms': '1ba'}, {'address': '156 Roseleah Ave, Newington, CT 06111', 'coordinates': {'latitude': 41.71366, 'longitude': -72.71912, '__typename': 'HOME_Coordinates'}, 'price': '$295,000', 'link': 'https://www.trulia.com/p/ct/newington/156-roseleah-ave-newington-ct-06111--2004837290', 'bedrooms': '3bd', 'bathrooms': '2ba'}, {'address': '37 Butternut Dr, East Hartford, CT 06118', 'coordinates': {'latitude': 41.75523, 'longitude': -72.596115, '__typename': 'HOME_Coordinates'}, 'price': '$270,000', 'link': 'https://www.trulia.com/p/ct/east-hartford/37-butternut-dr-east-hartford-ct-06118--2004867385', 'bedrooms': '3bd', 'bathrooms': '2ba'}, {'address': '1192 Trout Brook Dr, West Hartford, CT 06119', 'coordinates': {'latitude': 41.770657, 'longitude': -72.73642, '__typename': 'HOME_Coordinates'}, 'price': '$239,900', 'link': 'https://www.trulia.com/p/ct/west-hartford/1192-trout-brook-dr-west-hartford-ct-06119--2004872070', 'bedrooms': '3bd', 'bathrooms': '1ba'}, {'address': '40 Cleveland Ave, Hartford, CT 06120', 'coordinates': {'latitude': 41.79462, 'longitude': -72.66701, '__typename': 'HOME_Coordinates'}, 'price': '$239,900', 'link': 'https://www.trulia.com/p/ct/hartford/40-cleveland-ave-hartford-ct-06120--2004877763', 'bedrooms': '4bd', 'bathrooms': '2ba'}, {'address': '44 Brightview Dr, West Hartford, CT 06117', 'coordinates': {'latitude': 41.78946, 'longitude': -72.751335, '__typename': 'HOME_Coordinates'}, 'price': '$303,000', 'link': 'https://www.trulia.com/p/ct/west-hartford/44-brightview-dr-west-hartford-ct-06117--2004860214', 'bedrooms': '3bd', 'bathrooms': '3ba'}, {'address': '30 Kowal Ct, Newington, CT 06111', 'coordinates': {'latitude': 41.65506, 'longitude': -72.71265, '__typename': 'HOME_Coordinates'}, 'price': '$259,900', 'link': 'https://www.trulia.com/p/ct/newington/30-kowal-ct-newington-ct-06111--2004841493', 'bedrooms': '2bd', 'bathrooms': '2ba'}, {'address': '27 Kenyon Pl, East Hartford, CT 06108', 'coordinates': {'latitude': 41.77476, 'longitude': -72.6288, '__typename': 'HOME_Coordinates'}, 'price': '$169,900', 'link': 'https://www.trulia.com/p/ct/east-hartford/27-kenyon-pl-east-hartford-ct-06108--2004815091', 'bedrooms': '3bd', 'bathrooms': '2ba'}, {'address': '44 Sedgwick Rd, East Hartford, CT 06108', 'coordinates': {'latitude': 41.79585, 'longitude': -72.62273, '__typename': 'HOME_Coordinates'}, 'price': '$289,900', 'link': 'https://www.trulia.com/p/ct/east-hartford/44-sedgwick-rd-east-hartford-ct-06108--2004816722', 'bedrooms': '4bd', 'bathrooms': '2ba'}, {'address': '42 Woodridge Cir, West Hartford, CT 06107', 'coordinates': {'latitude': 41.730164, 'longitude': -72.75981, '__typename': 'HOME_Coordinates'}, 'price': '$699,900', 'link': 'https://www.trulia.com/p/ct/west-hartford/42-woodridge-cir-west-hartford-ct-06107--2004809358', 'bedrooms': '4bd', 'bathrooms': '3ba'}, {'address': '50 Hemlock St, Newington, CT 06111', 'coordinates': {'latitude': 41.689648, 'longitude': -72.74199, '__typename': 'HOME_Coordinates'}, 'price': '$279,777', 'link': 'https://www.trulia.com/p/ct/newington/50-hemlock-st-newington-ct-06111--1063993173', 'bedrooms': '2bd', 'bathrooms': '2ba'}, {'address': '8 Coolidge Rd, West Hartford, CT 06117', 'coordinates': {'latitude': 41.785965, 'longitude': -72.75728, '__typename': 'HOME_Coordinates'}, 'price': '$399,900', 'link': 'https://www.trulia.com/p/ct/west-hartford/8-coolidge-rd-west-hartford-ct-06117--2004861846', 'bedrooms': '3bd', 'bathrooms': '2ba'}, {'address': '178 W  Ridge Dr, West Hartford, CT 06117', 'coordinates': {'latitude': 41.78777, 'longitude': -72.758835, '__typename': 'HOME_Coordinates'}, 'price': '$559,900', 'link': 'https://www.trulia.com/p/ct/west-hartford/178-w-ridge-dr-west-hartford-ct-06117--2088454765', 'bedrooms': '4bd', 'bathrooms': '4ba'}, {'address': '128 Highland St, Wethersfield, CT 06109', 'coordinates': {'latitude': 41.683517, 'longitude': -72.67795, '__typename': 'HOME_Coordinates'}, 'price': '$850,000', 'link': 'https://www.trulia.com/p/ct/wethersfield/128-highland-st-wethersfield-ct-06109--2004820633', 'bedrooms': '4bd', 'bathrooms': '5ba'}, {'address': '985 Maple St, Wethersfield, CT 06109', 'coordinates': {'latitude': 41.67048, 'longitude': -72.66961, '__typename': 'HOME_Coordinates'}, 'price': '$389,000', 'link': 'https://www.trulia.com/p/ct/wethersfield/985-maple-st-wethersfield-ct-06109--2004829960', 'bedrooms': '3bd', 'bathrooms': '3ba'}, {'address': '178 Hunter Dr, West Hartford, CT 06107', 'coordinates': {'latitude': 41.76749, 'longitude': -72.77633, '__typename': 'HOME_Coordinates'}, 'price': '$769,900', 'link': 'https://www.trulia.com/p/ct/west-hartford/178-hunter-dr-west-hartford-ct-06107--2004806703', 'bedrooms': '5bd', 'bathrooms': '6ba'}, {'address': '67 Ringgold St, West Hartford, CT 06119', 'coordinates': {'latitude': 41.754868, 'longitude': -72.7191, '__typename': 'HOME_Coordinates'}, 'price': '$299,900', 'link': 'https://www.trulia.com/p/ct/west-hartford/67-ringgold-st-west-hartford-ct-06119--1064649502', 'bedrooms': '3bd', 'bathrooms': '2ba'}, {'address': '43 Hollywood Ave, West Hartford, CT 06110', 'coordinates': {'latitude': 41.72978, 'longitude': -72.71523, '__typename': 'HOME_Coordinates'}, 'price': '$210,000', 'link': 'https://www.trulia.com/p/ct/west-hartford/43-hollywood-ave-west-hartford-ct-06110--2004833091', 'bedrooms': '2bd', 'bathrooms': '1ba'}, {'address': '341 Main St, Wethersfield, CT 06109', 'coordinates': {'latitude': 41.716423, 'longitude': -72.6528, '__typename': 'HOME_Coordinates'}, 'price': '$399,900', 'link': 'https://www.trulia.com/p/ct/wethersfield/341-main-st-wethersfield-ct-06109--1063150956', 'bedrooms': '4bd', 'bathrooms': '2ba'}, {'address': '44 Seymour Ave, West Hartford, CT 06119', 'coordinates': {'latitude': 41.753174, 'longitude': -72.72396, '__typename': 'HOME_Coordinates'}, 'price': '$319,900', 'link': 'https://www.trulia.com/p/ct/west-hartford/44-seymour-ave-west-hartford-ct-06119--2004874602', 'bedrooms': '3bd', 'bathrooms': '2ba'}, {'address': '1655 Asylum Ave, West Hartford, CT 06117', 'coordinates': {'latitude': 41.778393, 'longitude': -72.72725, '__typename': 'HOME_Coordinates'}, 'price': '$450,000', 'link': 'https://www.trulia.com/p/ct/west-hartford/1655-asylum-ave-west-hartford-ct-06117--2004857933', 'bedrooms': '4bd', 'bathrooms': '2ba'}, {'address': '81 Central Ave, East Hartford, CT 06108', 'coordinates': {'latitude': 41.768265, 'longitude': -72.64077, '__typename': 'HOME_Coordinates'}, 'price': '$269,900', 'link': 'https://www.trulia.com/p/ct/east-hartford/81-central-ave-east-hartford-ct-06108--2004818823', 'bedrooms': '3bd', 'bathrooms': '2ba'}, {'address': '35 Monte Vista Ave, Newington, CT 06111', 'coordinates': {'latitude': 41.67905, 'longitude': -72.75242, '__typename': 'HOME_Coordinates'}, 'price': '$145,000', 'link': 'https://www.trulia.com/p/ct/newington/35-monte-vista-ave-newington-ct-06111--2004842262', 'bedrooms': '2bd', 'bathrooms': '1ba'}]
40
```

You can even get more details about each property(home) such as floorSpace, lotSize, and many more including the history of the property.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.